# Selenium webdriver with Java3.141

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am getting error that webdriver  type cannot be resolved.although I have imported all jar files. I am wondering what is missed.

Comment: Please, post some more information about your implementation and the errors you get

Comment: Can you please provide the code snippet? Also, mention the type of project (Maven/plain Java), And the error that you get. Providing more details (relevant) will help others to understand your issue easily.

Answer (score 0):

Keep Only selenium-server-standalone JAR as an external JAR.
Or keep only selenium-java JARs as an external JARs.
You will get this problem when both Jars are present.
Also do Project > Clean